# Git Flow Hotfix - Peer Review & merge into remote master & develop

Tags: git, github, git-flow, hotfix

I have a hotfix which I would like to submit for peer review.

I am using git-flow http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

git-flow doesn't appear to have a `git flow hotfix publish` command.

How I am tackling this is as follows:

local

```
git flow hotfix start v1.0.1
make changes to files, git add and git commit as normal.
git push
```

remote

```
Ask a team member to pull / review the hotfix branch
```

local

```
git flow hotfix finish
git push origin master
git push origin develop
git push --tags
```

remote

```
delete the hotfix branch
```

This seems a bit clunky. What I want is to be able to submit a pull request for the hotfix branch to both the develop and master branch on remote. I then want to be able to do a git pull on my local master and develop branches to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that hotfixes cannot be published (see [issue 92](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/92)).

But this feature has been implemented in this [gitflow fork (AVH Edition)](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow).

See [commit 0b324de](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow/commit/0b324def488f2e73e0db6109e440974f3aab265f): even if it isn't the exact sequence of commands you are after, you can easily adapt it to match your goal.